# CSS: Stacking Order Issue on Safari

Tags: css, safari, z-index

I am trying to create a shape using CSS, using the before and after pseudo elements. The shape renders as I'd expect in Chrome and Firefox, however in Safari the :before content ends up stacked on top of the :after content, and I'm not sure why. It looks like it has something to do with the transform in my :before element but I'm not sure what exactly I've done wrong, and why it's only different in Safari, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

[This is what I get on Chrome/Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H9nW.png)
 [and this is what I get in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPj9.png)

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  transform: rotate(27deg);
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.shape:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 36px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(70deg);
}
.shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 92px;
  height: 92px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:
    radial-gradient(blue 17%, transparent 19%),
    radial-gradient(red 26%, transparent 28%),
    radial-gradient(blue 40%, transparent 42%),
    red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the issue exactly (and I cannot test) but you can adjust the `:before` shape to consider a radial-gradient in order to create a transparent part and avoid the overlap even when the element is on the top.

Here is an example where I explicitely made the `:before` on the top and it works. I also reduced the code a little.

```css
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotate(27deg);
}

.shape:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 36px;
  top: 26px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 48px;
  background: radial-gradient(25px 23px at left,transparent 98%, blue 100%);
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(70deg);
  z-index:1;
}

.shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:4px solid blue;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(blue 17%, transparent 19%), 
   radial-gradient(red  26%, transparent 28%), 
   radial-gradient(blue 40%, transparent 42%), 
   red;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```